# measure theory: how does a function f in L1 induces a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In a measure space (X,$\mu$), let f $\in L^1$ and f$\ge$0. for every measurable set E let $\mu_f$=$\int_E$f = $\int_X$f$\chi_E$

1) show $\mu_f$ is a measure
do I have to show that f induces a measure on E of X? I'm no sure how to approach this problem. I have been thinking on using simple functions to approximate f but that's to show how $\mu_f$ is defined not $\mu_f$ as a measure. I haven't proved anything like this before so some extra details would be apreciated.

2) show if $\mu(E)$=0, then $\mu_f$=0
so I guess an f-induced measure here is dependent on the measurable space. I don't even know how $\mu$ is defined. Is E supposed to be the empty set in this case?

3) provide an examples where $\mu_f$=0 but $\mu$>0.
I was thinking the only way this is possible is if the function f sends everything in E to 0, but E is not empty so the induced metric doesn't measure everything.

I greatly appreciate your help, I'm trying to learn this well, so that I can do better dealing with dense functions in L1 and integrable functions in general.

Comment: For 2., the measure is not dependent on the space in the way you are arguing, E is a measurable set in the space, and not the space itself. It follows from the fact that the integral of a function over a set of measure zero is necessarily 0. The net effect is you are showing sets of measure zero in the original measure are also measure zero sets in the "induced" measure. #3 amounts to showing the converse doesn't hold. That is, a measure zero set in the induced measure is not necessarily zero in the original measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) So $\mu_f(E)= \int \chi_E f d\mu$ where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E$ (for $E$ a $\mu$-measurable set). So what are the axioms you need to check for $\mu_f$ to be a measure? First there would be $\mu_f(\emptyset)=0$, but this is easy right? (Do you see why?) What about the second axiom? Let $\{E_n\}$ be a pairwise disjoint, measurable collection of sets. We need to verify that $$\mu_f(\bigcup E_n) = \sum \mu_f(E_n)$$ right? Since the $E_n$ are pairwise disjoint we have $\chi_{\bigcup E_n} = \sum \chi_{E_n}$ (check this!). But then $$\mu_f(\bigcup E_n) = \int f \sum \chi_{E_n} d\mu = \sum \int f \chi_{E_n} d\mu$$  (Why was I able to interchange the series and the integral?) Thus $\mu_f$ is a measure.

2) If $E$ is $\mu$-null, i.e. $\mu(E)=0$, what can you say about $f \chi_E$?

3) There are many ways to go about this last question. The trivial one is to just let $f =0$. Yet we can do better with not too much technicalities, just let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ and take any $\mu$-nullset, let's say $N$ is such a set, and define $f= \chi_N$. What is $\mu_f$ then?

Comment: in #1 we're able to exchange the series and the integral because f is non-negative and integrable (in L1), correct? now, in #3, we chose the borel $\sigma$ algebra because with the Lebesgue measure, all its sets are >0 but the induced measure on N is based on the elements it contains which is null. Am I on the right track?

Comment: #1 follows from the Monotone convergence theorem! Actually you don't need $f$ to be in $L^1(\mu)$ to ensure that $\mu_f$ is a measure (can you see that this assumption isn't really used?). However the additional condition $f \in L^1(\mu)$ ensures, that $\mu_f$ is a finite measure (why?). In #3 we just choose $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure, since this is a non-zero measure on the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ (all nonempty intervals have positive measure) and remember, that integration over nullsets always gives the result $0$ (can you show that too?)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $E_1,E_2,\dots $ are pairwise disjoint and measurable. Then

$$\chi_{E_1\cup E_2 \cup \dots} = \sum_n\chi_{E_n}.$$

Comment: i need help proving it, i understand the concepts but need help with process

Comment: @learning_mathematician You need to show that it is countably additive, that is $\mu_f(\cup E_i) = \sum_i \mu_f(E_i)$ for disjoint $E_i$ Use the above to show that the integral over a union of disjoint sets is equal to the sum of the integrals over each set.

Comment: @learning_mathematician Here is how one shows #2: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725749/show-that-int-e-f-d-mu-0-if-mue-0?rq=1